# How to Score an MLP Classifier

Tags: scikit-learn, perceptron

I am trying to understand MLP Classifiers, but would like to know what the best way to create a score is. e.g. preferably a normalized score between 0 and 1.

For instance, I looked at Scikit-learn's MLP Regressor which uses a score of

$1 - u / v$, where $u = \sum(TRUE - PREDICT)^{2}$
and $v = \sum (TRUE - AVGTRUE)^2 .$

see: [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.score)

I can't see a way of extending this to Classifier problems. Scikit-Learn's [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.score) is (to me at least) not very clear on what the Classifier score actually is, as in what the calculation is.

I would like to know a standard, or recommended, function for calculating a Classifier score (not necessarily Scikit-Learn's).

Comment: If you don't write out what you mean by "MLP", I'm going to assume you're trying to classify My Little Pony characters. It's a hard problem, now that we have 7 seasons and several movies.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking the loss function in classification setting. You may read [this page in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification). Here is a short version:

- If the classifier is outputting a binary label in binary classification problem,  [0-1 loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function#0-1_loss_function) can be used.
- If the classifier is outputting a probability number in binary classification problem, [logistic loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification#Logistic_loss) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The value you give is the [Coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) which is by no means the best choice for optimizing a regression problem. There are multiple options and you must decide based on your problem. I tend to use [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) or [MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) if I want to be less sensitive to outliers. The Coefficient of determination is mainly used because it is normalized.

For binary classification the situation gets more complicated. I would read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers) to get some idea or your options. Many are easily availiable in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics). I would recommend you think about which type of error you are most concerned about. For example in many problems the most important issue is [Sensitivity or Precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) so you want to evaluate based on one of them alone. A good combined metric is the [Matthews correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient) but as with regression you must decide what your goal is.